# Internal Imports from Subproject in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I have the following structure:

```
│
├── pckg1/
│   └── utils/
│         ├── module11.py
│         └── module12.py
│
├── pckg2/
│   └── utils/
│         ├── module21.py
│         └── module22.py
│
└── main_pckg/
    ├── utils/
    └── main.py
```

When I run `main.py`, I import required methods from both `module11.py` and `module21.py` under `utils` directories under from  `pckg1` and `pckg2`.

In side those modules there are some local imports. For Example (`pckg1/utils/module11.py`):

```
from utils.module21 import X,Y,Z
```

when I run `main_pckg/main.py`, the following error naturally raises:

```
No module named `utils/module21` under the current working dir.
```

Since there is no module21

A naive solution is to modify those imports to relative import:

```
from ..utils.module21 import X,Y,Z
```

But I have many modules and subprojects with are tracked and shall not be modified.

Any workarounds to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Python is trying to reach those files from main.py.

You can add those folders to path from main file.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../pckg1/utils')
sys.path.append('../pckg2/utils')
```

After that you won't need to specify the folder name

```
from module21 import x, y, z
```

should work